# Finding latitude and longitude of multiple addresses

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I am building a restaurant application for which i have created a database which includes name of restaurant.phone number,address,and latitude and longitude.Latitude and longitude is for finding the location.The problem is that i have 2201 restaurants and i need to find the latitude and longitude of all.I am using http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/
to find latitude and longitude.but its a very lengthy process.Is there any other way to get latitude and longitude of multiple locations?

Comment: Whats the problem with Android GeoCoder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GetLatLon](http://www.getlatlon.com/).com . Its my favorite.

Comment: but it does not give the accurate latitude and longitude

Comment: it gives the lat and lon of the center. For me it gives perfect and accurate geo locations.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Android provide a simple way with [**Android GeoCoder**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class, For getting Latitude and longitude from Location address or vice-verse, (So you don't need any other service for it)

```
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> address;

try {
    address = coder.getFromLocationName(locAddress,1);
    if (address == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Address location = address.get(0);
    Log.e("Latitude: " +location.getLatitude(),"Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
}
```

Also include permission in manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.But the solution you gave is possible for a single address.I have 2201 addresses.

Answer (score 1):

if u have a address array than u can easily find multiple address latitude and longitude,here is a link of google api http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ahmedabad&sensor=false inplace of ahmedabad u can pass ur address u can call this api for multiple address than from json response u can fetch latitude and longitude and store them in an array.in my project i have done like this,it's an easiest way
Best Of luck 
Aamirkhan I.

Answer (score 0):

To get accurate location coordinates you can use below sites,

http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html

http://www.whatsmygps.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false

try this web service of google.. just give the address in the above web services and in response u'll get the location details...

eg: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Pune&sensor=false

will give u the location of pune...